# Changing the name of an attribute of generated join table in Entity Framework (many-to-many relationships),

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I created two models, Order (for orders at the shop) and ShopItem (for shop product). These two models have got many-to-many relationships. They are below:

The Order model

```cs
public class Order
{
    [Key]
    public string order_id { get; set; }
    public List<ShopItem> Items { get; set; }
    //some other info...
}
```

The ShopItem model

```cs
public class ShopItem
{
    [Key, Column("shop_item_id")]
    public string ItemId { get; set; }
    public List<Order> Orders { get; set; }
    //some other info...
}
```

To provide many-to-many relationships in DBContext I do the next thing:

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Order>()
        .HasMany(a => a.Items)
        .WithMany(a => a.Orders)
        .UsingEntity("OrderItemJoinTable");
}
```

After making the migration I get a table called OrderItemJoinTable with attributes like: ItemsItemId;
Ordersorder_id.
The problem is that I need a proper names for them like "item_id" and "order_id". How can I change the names of such attributes in this table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include the column names in the configuration.

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Order>()
            .HasMany(a => a.Items)
            .WithMany(a => a.Orders)
            .UsingEntity(j => 
            {
                j.ToTable("OrderItemJoinTable");
                j.Property("ItemsItemId").HasColumnName("item_id");
                j.Property("Ordersorder_id").HasColumnName('order_id')
            };
    }
```